# How enforce filling up the user profile after first social login in django-allauth?

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth

I've created `UserProfile` model in my application:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                primary_key=True,
                                verbose_name=_('user'),
                                related_name='user_profile')
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=85)
    voivodship = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                  choices=Vovoidship.choices,
                                  validators=[Vovoidship.validator])
    postcode = models.IntegerField()
    street = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    building = models.SmallIntegerField()
    premises = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    phonenumber = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)

    @staticmethod
    def post_save_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(UserProfile.post_save_create, sender=User)
```

Now, I felt into my own trap. I don't want to loose constraints and keep the requirement in the database that address fields need to be filled up. I'm using `django-allauth`. While using the setting `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'management.forms.SignupForm'` solves the problem for *traditional* sign up form, if the user logs in first time using the social account I got hit by constraint violation for obvious reasons:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/google/login/callback/
null value in column "postcode" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, , , null, , null, , ).
```

Hence the question, how to correctly implement the request for filling up the information for fields in the application `UserProfile`? I'm surprised that `django-allauth` doesn't have a build in handler for that the same way as `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS` is done.

As I'm **new** to Django please assume I rather don't know something than it should be obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some credits to [davka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3122083/davka) I've managed to form a working solution which required creating `UserProfile` object inside `signup()` method of the `SignupForm` class, but because of database/model constrains it has be be filled with data **during creation**. The result:

```
class SignupForm(ModelForm):
    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ['user', 'phonenumber']

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user, defaults={
                'locality': self.cleaned_data['locality'],
                'voivodship': self.cleaned_data['voivodship'],
                'postcode': self.cleaned_data['postcode'],
                'street': self.cleaned_data['street'],
                'building': self.cleaned_data['building'],
                'premises': self.cleaned_data['premises'],
            })
        if created: # This prevents saving if profile already exist
            profile.save()
```

The solution doesn't totally fit into DRY principle, but shows the idea. Going further it could probably iterate over results matching model fields.

Two elements need to be set correctly in `settings.py`:

- `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'yourapp.forms.SignupForm'` to enable this form in `allauth`
- `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False` this - contrary to the intuition - let the `allauth` display the form before finishing the signup **if** the user selected social sign in but don't have an account; it works safely if the account already exists (username and/or e-mail address depending on other settings) as just does't allow to finish registration (*why they call it sign up?*) and the user is forced to log in and link social account.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

1.- Create your custom Signup Class, for you to do the additional work

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
    locality = forms.CharField(max_length=85)
    voivodship = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    postcode = forms.IntegerField()
    etc.

    def signup(self, request, user):
        # I think the profile will exist at this point based on
        # your post_save_create. But if not, just create it here
        if user.user_profile:
             user.user_profile.locality = self.cleaned_data['locality']
             user.user_profile.voivodship = self.cleaned_data['voivodship']
             user.user_profile.postcode = self.cleaned_data['postcode']
             ...
             user.user_profile.save()
```

2.- Set `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'yourproject.yourapp.forms.SignupForm'` to have allauth use your form

3.- Set `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP=False` to ensure the form is presented even with social signup.

Comment: Documentation for 1.9 discourages from creating own User Model but advises to implement a user profile as OneToOne relationship. So I followed. For me it's not so bad idea as I don't need to worry if other packages can work with my modified model. I'll check your answer (I already have SignupForm) and let you know. I think the missing piece could be SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP=False.

Comment: Really? I cannot find that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user). Do you have a reference? Anyway, nothing wrong with user profiles, especially if they don't always have to be loaded, but if they are, you are always doing two queries. On the other hand, it is not good to store a lot of extra info on the User Profile that is not needed often.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model The green box is one example. More is expressed in several notes across this page.

Comment: Yes, it is not that is not recommended but that you should have a reason for it. Anyway, profiles are fine. Hope you confirm my answer is correct and can be accepted. I will remove the part on using User extensions as that is not relevant anyway

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. I added SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP=False to settings.py and now from social sign in it leads me to sign up form for existing user instead of logging in (Google provider) :-( I tend to believe I need to hack allauth to get it on a right track.

Comment: Can you confirm this happens over and over? It may be that because it was on before, it now needs to ask at least once

Comment: My bad. The account didn't have the social account assigned (remnant of initial attempts). I need to fix my SignupForm class. The only thing I don't like is that all fields have to be filled up by the user just at first stage of non-social signup... Busy working on fixes for SignupForm, be back in a while...

Comment: Doesn't work. I cannot go into details right now, but user.user_profile seem to not exist as you expected. I'll return to the problem tomorrow.

Comment: I think you can just create at that time if it doesn't exist. And maybe remove your post_save_create. Good luck!

Comment: I managed to go somewhere with working version, however far from your original answer. Hint: UserProfile object has to be created with all fields filled up inside signup() method of SignupForm class.

Comment: You should post your own answer then to help others

Comment: I'm going to do it ;-)

Comment: Hmm... how to share the bounty? I'd like to compensate your efforts to help, but you helped partially. If I bump up the answer, it'll land over mine, while in details it's wrong and may mislead less inquiring mind.

Comment: I specifically said you may need to create the User Profile. The rest are just details specific to your implementation. You could have asked me to just correct my answer, if you wanted to see that extra detail before up voting. Anyway, glad you got your solution.

Comment: Heh, we find the hole in the basic principle of stackoverflow - answers cannot be cooperative... in terms of the prize for votes up. Should I raise it on meta?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105202/discussion-between-davka-and-michal-f).